# How to return values of multi-choice Sharepoint field in an email in Power Automate?

Tags: arrays, sharepoint, sendmail, power-automate, getvalue

I have a sharepoint list with a column "Department", which is a choice list allows multiple selections. I want to send an email to users by creating a HTML column with some column details including this "Department column" values. But while running every fields have the appropriate data, but Department field has value, something like
"**[{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":5,"Value":"External"}]". How can I get the value "External from "Value: External".**

My list have almost 74 items, So I want to send an email within a HTML table with all these items along with Department column details. I am trying to send this in a single email. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure I understand, you want to extract “External” from that json?

Comment: @Skin Thank you for your response, Yes exactly. I want to extract "External" from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I created this flow which is basically your JSON in to the first variable and then the second variable extracts **"External"** from the `value` property.

[image: Flow]

**Note**: *The JSON engine in PA doesn't like @odata.type so I removed the @ to make it work.*

In the second action, this is the expression ...

```
variables('Data')[0]['value']
```

I'm getting the first element in the array and then from that element, I'm extracting the value of the `value` property.

This is the result ...

[image: Result]